# RealmSwift show errors after update 1.0

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I've updated my existing project to Realm 1.0 by using cocoapods and then I clean and build the project. Then RealmSwift show lots of errors.

[image]

[image]

Is this some kind of Bug in Realm or what's the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've updated my existing project to Realm 1.0

So you're now using a library that's been designed to work with the latest version of Swift.

But you're using it in the same Xcode version as before, so your Swift version is now too old for this library.

You have to update Xcode to the latest version (7.3.1 at the time of this answer) in order to use the latest version of the library.

Comment: But In Realm documentation shows that we can use this update for swift 2.2.

Comment: Yes, that's my point exactly - looking at your screenshots, it seems that your Xcode doesn't recognize the Swift 2.2 syntax used by the library. Update Xcode! :)

Comment: Ohh OK I'll update my Xcode and I will update, Thanks :)